# delayed job unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I setup delayed job and it was working fine for a while. Suddenly i get `unknown attribute: queue`  when try to add the following line to one of my controllers:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(EmailJob.new())
```

any hints?

Comment: What have you tried?  What line number and full error message do you get.  Just edit your question with the details, and you'll get help right away -- you just need to do enough work to give the good folks who help here enough to help you :-)  (And as @Veraticus noted, Stack Overflow works when you also give people who do answer your questions credit for doing so by marking answers as accepted).

Answer (score 6):

You need to run
rails generate delayed_job:upgrade

Refer https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/453